# Add Active Class to Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have a side menu and I want to display the active class when it loads the page.

The obvious answer would be to do this with jquery in every page but it repeats tons of code and it's boring.

So I used this in a app.js globally:

```
//Active side-menu
$('.nav-item').click(function () {
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

But this doesn't work because it puts active and when it loads the page this class is removed after loading the html

What can I do?

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="general-setup" onclick="gitLabFetch()" id="createEnviromentTab">
            <img src="../resources/img/icons/create-icon.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
            <span class="menu-title">Create Environment</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    //A lot of li elements
<ul>
```

Comment: The active class is determined by the user clicking a li do you want this active class persistent beyond the session?

Comment: IMO, the class should be added server side

Comment: @zer00ne i just want to put active class in the current tab the user is in. I only have 1 jsp file with the side menu and I load like this: `<%@include file="side-menu.jsp" %>`

Answer (score 3):

I think that on page load, you should get the url, try to find it on the menu with javascript and then add the active class to the nav-item, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
    $('ul.nav a.nav-link[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');    
});
```

A little example, you might need to tweak the url part:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'general-setup';//window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
    $('ul.nav a.nav-link[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');    
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="general-setup" onclick="gitLabFetch()" id="createEnviromentTab">
          <img src="../resources/img/icons/create-icon.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
          <span class="menu-title">Create Environment</span>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="general-setup2" onclick="gitLabFetch()" id="createEnviromentTab">
          <img src="../resources/img/icons/create-icon.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
          <span class="menu-title">Create Environment</span>
      </a>
  </li>
 //A lot of li elements
<ul>
```

Comment: it's not adding the active class. the url is right tho.

Comment: what's the output of `console.log(url);` ?

Comment: general-setup. it's correct. I put it on the footer with document ready so it should work.

Comment: what is the output of `console.log($('ul.nav a.nav-link[href="' + url + '"]'))`?
 can you post a jsfiddle with all the menu? the ul and child li elements?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after further thought i have come up with a solution.
An approach i would take is to add a `data` attribute to anchor onto, this gives you the freedom to define routes that your list items link to and style them accordingly based on route...

```js
(() => {
  $('li')
  .filter((i, li) => $(li).data('route') === window.location.pathname)
  .addClass('active')
})()
```

```html
<li data-route="/">HOME</li>
<li data-route="/friends">Friends</li>
<li data-route="/profile">Profile</li>
<li data-route="/blog">Blog</li>
```

As you can see, i run over all the list-items and filter out all the items that do not have `data-route` attributes that match the `window.location.pathname`, after i am left with the filtered list, i apply an active class to the matched items.